# How to control bandwidth using this modem?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, internet-connection, modem

I'm using this [FIBERHOME AN5506-04-FG](https://www.google.co.id/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.jualo.com%2Foriginal%2F10323097%2Fmodem-fiber-optic-gpo-komputer-modem-router-10323097.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jualo.com%2Fkomputer-modem-router%2Fiklan-modem-fiber-optic-gpon-fiberhome-an5506-dual-antena-wifi&docid=hYw5XqHzYlF-cM&tbnid=JzrihSttHlHxgM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj-vbvD5N3XAhXEsI8KHe49B0cQMwhvKEAwQA..i&w=640&h=480&bih=947&biw=1920&q=modem%20fiberhome%20an5506&ved=0ahUKEwj-vbvD5N3XAhXEsI8KHe49B0cQMwhvKEAwQA&iact=mrc&uact=8) modem router in my house. I set only 5 device that can connect to the internet.But, I cannot set the speed/bandwith per device.

There is QOS Control in the router setting. But, there is no menu to set bandwith control so I can limit connection another user to about 50-100kbps per user.

Are there any alternative method to limit connection or control bandwith of other user?

Answer (score 0):

see this picture taken from overclock.net: 
[image]

Comment: are there a tutorial for this setting? I am not fully understand  this

Comment: I could not find any proper manual for it, but in principle you set a priority for each route between two ip addresses (the source and the target). The ip-"routes" with highest priority get the most data shoved through the pipeline